# get the name of task's creator, time of creation

Tags: flask, celery

I'm launching some big task with processing file in the background using celery and `delay()` function. I need after setting up task get who launch it, time of launching and updating task. How can i get it? If i 'm not mistaken, object of type `AsyncResult` doesn't have such fields (i am a newbie at flask :(  ).

I have looked throw this site https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html but haven't seen the field that i need.

```py
task = some_func.delay(path_to_file)
...

return jsonify({
    'id': task.id,
    'status':task.status,
    'creator': # process who created this task,
    'time_creation': # time of creation of this task
})


@celery.task
some_func(path_to_file):
    # some work with file background
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can reliably get is the host from which the task was sent, if you enable the [task-sent event](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-send-sent-event). Task-sent event contains the timestamp when the task was created. As you already mentioned, AsyncResult can be used to track the state changes - all you have to do is to periodically check the `.state` property of the AsyncResult.